How python sklearn module's SVM classifier deal with the categorical feature with one-hot code?
I know I need to make my categorical feature to one-hot code to make my SVM classifier use the categorical feature. But I don't find the theory and detail about how this method can work.
So I want to ask here.

Consider asking at the CrossValidated StackExchange for input on the theory @JudeW. To do it in sklearn, you can create a pipeline that runs OneHotEncoder followed by SVC/LinearSVC/SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', ...).
